# Increasing the file size in flume with memory channel

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, flume, flume-ng

Below is my flume config file. Even after the changing the rollInterval and rollSize only 10 events is getting written also the console shows rollCount=10 and events=10. Also I tried increasing the rollCount to 1000 but no change in output. Can anyone suggest to increase the file size being written in hdfs. Whats wrong with the below conf file?

```
#naming components 

NetAgent.sources = NetCat_1 NetCat_2
NetAgent.sinks = HDFS
NetAgent.channels = MemChannel


NetAgent.sources.NetCat_1.type = netcat
NetAgent.sources.NetCat_1.bind = localhost
NetAgent.sources.NetCat_1.port = 8671

NetAgent.sources.NetCat_2.type = netcat
NetAgent.sources.NetCat_2.bind = localhost
NetAgent.sources.NetCat_2.port = 8672


NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = file path here
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.filePrefix = test
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 67108864
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 3600
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.rollCount = 0
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream


NetAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
NetAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 20000
NetAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 20000


NetAgent.sources.NetCat_1.channels = MemChannel
NetAgent.sources.NetCat_2.channels = MemChannel
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
```

The console logs as

```
(SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUg-org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.shouldRotate(BucketWriter.java)]
rolling: rollCount: 10, events: 10
```

[the image shows the files written in HDFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9MjO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add hdfs to your rollCount configuration.  It is using the default value of 10 because it doesn't see your configuration.  Notice that your config for HDFS is:

```
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 67108864
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 3600
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.rollCount = 0
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
```

In the rollCount line, it needs to be:

```
NetAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0
```

This will override the default rollCount and your Flume agent will behave how you want it to.